# Cannot push to Heroku (gemfile.lock issue)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

## Summary:

When pushing to my staging app, Heroku complains that `bundle install` failed and that I need to run `bundle install` elsewhere and version the resulting `Gemfile.lock`.  The problem is that I've *already* done this and committed it.

How do I fix this?

---

### Issue:

Due to some inherited awfulness at work, I had to debug and fix several things in production.  Everything's working now, but this means our `master` branch is ahead of `staging` by 10+ commits, including some gem changes.  I merged them and attempted to push to my staging app on Heroku.

However, I didn't run `bundle install` after merging in the changes (shame on me), so Heroku correctly complained.

To fix this, I ran the standard:

```
bundle install
git add Gemfile.lock
git commit -m "Updated gem bundle"
git push staging
```

However, Heroku is still complaining about `Gemfile.lock`:

```
Counting objects: 228, done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (179/179), done.
Writing objects: 100% (192/192), 24.38 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 192 (delta 127), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/ruby
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.2
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
remote:        your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
remote:        updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
remote:        You have deleted from the Gemfile:
remote:        * ruby-drupal-hash
remote:        Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
remote:        your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
remote:        updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
remote:
remote:        You have deleted from the Gemfile:
remote:        * ruby-drupal-hash
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to redacted-staging.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/redacted-staging.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/redacted-staging.git'
```

Also:

- `Gemfile.lock` is *not* in `.gitignore`
- `bundle install` runs fine, and does not update any gems (as I've run it several times now).
- To verify my sanity, I checked `git status` and `git log` to ensure I actually added and committed the changes; I'm apparently not crazy (though please correct me if i'm wrong).

#### To reiterate:

> I have ***already*** run `bundle install` and added & committed `Gemfile.lock`

How do I fix this?

What am I missing?

---

---

## Update:

I've tried

- running `bundle update` which updated 26 gems; committing the new `Gemfile.lock` and pushing results in the same error.
- Deleting and re-bundling produces an identical `Gemfile.lock`.  Adding a newline and pushing results in the same error.
- Removing Bundler's version info from `Gemfile.lock` and pushing results in the same error.
- I even re-addded the `ruby-drupal-hash` gem, ran `bundle install`, and pushed the new `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` files.  Interestingly, the error message about me deleting `ruby-drupal-hash` persisted despite it being present again.

Comment: Have you tried running bundle update? That should generate a new Gemfile.lock. Of course if your version dependencies are loose lots of things could change. Running bundle install will only install the versions specified in the Gemfile.lock and will complain that you have incompatible versions.

Comment: You get into nightmares when your predecessors didn't specify dependencies correctly. Take **gem 'rails', '~> 3.0.0'** the ~> says that bundle update can take tiny version changes (e.g. 3.0.4). If all your dependencies are specified this way bundle update is less traumatic  Have you tried editing the Gemfile.lock file and manually fixing it?.

Comment: I did not.  Running `bundle update` updated 26 gems.  I added the new Gemfile.lock and committed it as before; pushing to Heroku, however, still gives me the same error.  What else could be causing this?

Comment: Bummer.  What happens when you run **heroku run "ruby -v"** ?

Comment: Production, Staging, and Development (local) are all running `ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: That looks right.  Open your Gemfile.lock does it say that version?  Hmmm. This person had a similar problem (look near the [bottom](http://www.unityisplural.com/2010/11/hobo-finally.html)).

Comment: Last ditch (then I am going to bed) try **bundle inject ruby-drupal-hash"=0.0.3"**

Comment: `Gemfile.lock` doesn't specify a ruby version (Heroku pulls this from `Gemfile` instad, which shows 2.2.2).  The blog you linked was a very interesting and relatable read, but unfortuantely its advice (removing bundler's version info) did not have an effect.

Comment: running `bundle inject ruby-drupal-hash "0.0.3"` and `bundle install` then adding & committing both `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` and pushing... no change in error message.   I am becoming increasingly certain the cause of this error has nothing to do with the gemfiles at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was deceptively simple (of course):

> `git push staging staging:master`

---

The issue was that I was on the `staging` branch and needed to update my Heroku staging server's `master` branch.

Shame on me for overlooking something so obvious!
... and shame on Heroku's *decidedly* unhelpful output.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are working locally on different OS then your server is, for example windows vs Unix.

In order to fix it you simply have to build it with the following flag:

```
bundle install --deployment
```

If this is not working as well, simply delete the .lock file and let it be generated again in the same flow as you did before with install/update

Comment: Correct: my dev env is Mint, while staging+production is on Heroku.
anyway, I will try this.

Comment: So this might be your problem i assume. The answer should fix your problem.

Comment: No: Heroku handles the installing of gems itself -- it requires Gemfile.lock to know which versions to install, then runs `bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment` itself upon pushing (as shown in the output I provided).  This means I don't need to run `--deployment` locally (and doing so does not help).

My issue is that, for some reason, Heroku isn't seeing the `Gemfile.lock` that I'm committing and pushing.  It's acting like it simply isn't getting the file, or it's complaining for some other reason I have yet to deduce.

Comment: Have you tried the second option i mentioned? delete and create the file again?

Comment: Yes; unfortunately, deleting and re-generating `Gemfile.lock` results in an identical file.  I added a blank line to the bottom and added&commited -- same error upon pushing to Heroku.  Definition of insanity.  Besides a missing/incorrect `Gemfile.lock`, what else could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, trying to run `bundle update` or if it didn't work, I think this line it's look interesting:

```
remote:        You have deleted from the Gemfile:
remote:        * ruby-drupal-hash
remote:        Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
remote:        your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
remote:        updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
remote:
remote:        You have deleted from the Gemfile:
remote:        * ruby-drupal-hash
```

Comment: My question states that I've already run `bundle install`, and added & commited `Gemfile.lock` -- pushing gives me the same error.  Running `bundle update` and pushing the newly generated `Gemfile.lock` has no effect: Heroku still gives me the same error message.

Comment: could you to share your Gemfile?

Comment: Would that help?  It isn't a gem conflict or a malformed file.  and honestly, I'd rather not: It's for a production site; also, I inherited this app, and it's a huge mess.  However, I'll share it (with some security edits) if doing so would actually be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is complaining about ruby-drupal-hash being removed from Gemfile but Gemfile.lock not reflecting it.

```
You have deleted from the Gemfile:
remote:        * ruby-drupal-hash
```

I would check the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock for that particular gem and see if that is the problem.

Comment: neither Gemfile nor Gemfile.lock contain that gem, nor the text 'drupal' anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

For future internet explorers, I had a similar situation.

I had to change the version of a gem dependency, so I had to manually add "Execjs, '2.7.0'" to my gemfile, since another gem update had pulled it to 2.8.0 and that was causing an issue on Heroku.

Once I got the dependency updated, I removed the gem from the gemfile (while it remained in the gemfile.lock) and never did a `bundle install` to clean up the gemfile.lock  When I tried to push to Heroku, it broke and I got the same error.

To fix, I ran `bundle install` on the master branch and then committed the new gemfile.lock and then pushed to Heroku and it deployed as expected.

VERY stressful morning for me! :-)